# Windows 2008 R2 проброс записи звука по RDP

Tags: windows, аудио, rdp, windows-server

Добрый день,

Целые сутки пытаюсь пробросить устройство записи через RDP на Windows 2008 Enterprise R2.Все сделал, как положено и реестр и групповые политики (как указано и на сайте мс, и в выжимках [тут](http://argon.pro/blog/2011/11/rdp-remote-audio-recording/) и [тут](http://blog.waynehartman.com/articles/189.aspx)).

Ну не доступно оно у меня и все, хоть ты тресни! Может из-за того, что терминальный доступ в триальном режиме? Что не так?

Мои скриншоты 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Честно говоря сейчас не вспомню, но что-то я не помню там слишком больших проблем.

Визуально - мануалы хорошие...

Ну, естественно в опциях клиента нужно не забывать звук включать. Если вы сидите терминал в терминале, то конечно желательно попробовать напрямую.

Comment: @silverlce ну вот большие или не большие, но проблемы есть. Попробовал на 3ех различных win2008. Что-то еще надо. Сижу напрямую

Answer (score 0):

У тебя на сервере нет устройств аудиовоспроизведения и записи. То есть нет звука на сервере, нечего пробрасывать по RDP.
Установи драйвера на звук, но подозреваю что у тебя скорее отсутствует сама звуковая карта. Чаще всего их нет в серверах.

Comment: Приятно видеть ответ через 10 лет после вопроса))

Comment: Даже если он вкорне не верный)

Comment: Я бы в этом месте поставил асио и пульнул бы внешний стрим ффмпегом